# Explicitly destroying an activity in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android app where I want to explicitly destroy an activity once it has stopped.activity.onFinish() not serving the  purpose as it returns to the previous activity.

Example of my situation:
When I move from MainActivity to another activity,say B, I want to destroy the mainactivity. So that on pressing back from B now, I will move out of the application.Is that possible?

MainActivity code:

```
new Helper(this).startVerification();
```

In Helper class:

```
Helper{

  Context myContext;
  Helper(Context c){
  this.myContext=c;
 }

//other methods

  public void startVerification(){
    prepareForVerificationStart();
    Intent i=new Intent(myContext,VerificationNumberEntryActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    myContext.startActivity(i);
    Activity a=(Activity) myContext;
    a.finish();

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `startActivity()` to launch B, also call `finish()` to get rid of `MainActivity`.

Comment: Or adding a flag to the Intent `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

Comment: @CoomonsWare I am calling finish() inside onStop() of mainactivity.But that is not destroying the main activity.I am able to arrive at mainactivity by pressing back button.

Comment: @pratim, you shouldn't call `finish()` in `onStop()`, that's not defined behavior.

Comment: @323go In my case I am moving to next activity not directly from main activity, but through a helper class(created in context to main activity) usnig FLAG_NEW_TASK. So my code dont return to mainactivity from the helper class.Where should I put finish() in this case?

Comment: @pratim: "I am calling finish() inside onStop() of mainactivity" -- that is not what I advised you to do. Remove it from there and put the `finish()` call on the next Java statement after the `startActivity()` call where you start up B.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have uploaded my exact codes in my question.Is that correct?Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for achieving exactly what you're asking.
I'm using it in my own app, after the user has logged in, to destroy the login activity so the user cant press back to return to the login activity.

```
    Activity tmpAct = getActivity();
    Intent i = new Intent(tmpAct, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    tmpAct.finish();
```

Basically i save the current activity (login activity), then start the new one, and then do .finish() on the saved activity.

Comment: Why would you need to "save" the current `Activity`? You're still in the same context after running `startActivity()`. You can drop the first line of that snippet and simply invoke `getActivity().finish()`.

Comment: I did that at first, but encountered issues with getActivity() being null for a short amount of time after calling startActivity(i), so thats why i arrived at this solution.